# How to run SQL server on top of Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-explorer

We're using Azure Data Explorer for our big data queries. Now there's a request to pull data from ADX into SQL server for some types of queries.

Is this possible and if so how to do it?

Comment: can you share more about the motivation for moving the data into SQL server? different solutions can be proposed according to the need.

Comment: We want to migrate our on-premise sql server db to ADX. We use SSIS to process the data. Some of the work in the SSIS can be done in ADX but some transformations are pretty complex so we think we can't easily migrate them to queries in ADX. Thus our thinking is to pull data from ADX into SQL in order to do the complex parts there.
Not sure it makes sense though.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, [ADX supports a subset of the Microsoft SQL Server communication protocol (MS-TDS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/), with a subset of the T-SQL query language. One can connect to the T-SQL endpoint of an ADX cluster with any SQL client tool that supports AAD authentication.

If data export from ADX to SQL is required, using [export to SQL command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-sql) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to run SQL on top of ADX natively. However, you can create some kind of listener that listens for events and forwards them to both SQL and ADX. But, this solution may become very difficult to support over time.

Comment: How about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/tdskql ? Could it be an option?

Comment: seems that it can be a way to go, but unfortunately, I have no experience with this setup.